# Node Js with Azure WebApp using VSCODE

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code

Recently i have deployed a node.js server side app with budo and it works fine.. but after deploying to Azure(WebAPP) it is not working and throws error that '**require**' is not defined. I have used **VSCode** to develop the project

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found that the [bodu](https://github.com/mattdesl/budo) which is a `browserify` development server. So it looks like your app is in client-side JavaScript but the node.js app is in server-site, they are technically different. And `require()` does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript, so it raised your issue.

To fix this issue please try using a modular script loader like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to traverse all your sources and concatenate all `required` files into the `bundle` then including *bundle.js* in your HTML file. Finally, redeploy it and you will get it worked.

Any further concern or if I have any misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, Budo works on port 9966, after deployment will the same work with it? or do i have to implement it in another way?

Comment: As Budo is a local development server designed to work with browserify and Azure Web Apps is a production web server, so you should use Browserify to bundle up your JS before deploying to Azure App Service instead of deploying Budo to Azure.